# Edit function is INSERT instead of UPDATE CakePHP 2.1

Tags: cakephp, insert, edit, cakephp-2.1

I'm not exactly new to CakePHP though this is my first app in 2.x.  I'm using the baked controller & view and am having a problem with the edit function.

For starters, here is what was baked:

```
public function edit($id = null) {
        $this->User->id = $id;
        if (!$this->User->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }
        if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        } else {
            $this->request->data = $this->User->read(null, $id);
        }
    }
```

When this is left alone

```
if (!$this->User->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }
```

I'm told that I have an invalid user, even when I know without a doubt that the user does exist.

If I change it to this:

```
 if (!$this->User->exists($id)) {
                    throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
                }
```

The correct edit form comes up, and is populated with the correct data, but then upon save it tries to INSERT instead of Update.

Typically this is because CakePHP doesn't have an ID to work with but there is a hidden ID field in the form and I have even tried to force the issue by putting the following before the save.

```
$this->request->data['User']['id'] = $id;
```

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: "I have even tried to force the issue" => if you do that your code looks 100% foolprove. to me it should update correctly... did you debug the $id? is it empty by any chance on POST? you need to leave the "id" as hidden input in the form in order to post to the correct url (with id attached) - that might be your issue here.

Comment: I think you're right. I feel dumb for not investigating more but I tried to get to the edit page with using anything for the ID parameter and it still populates the form "correctly" (there is only one user in the table, so it's populating it with that user regardless of what I enter for the ID in the URL).  I'll have to figure out what's up here.

Comment: debug() your data on the line before the save and post it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function edit($id = null) {
        if (!$this->User->exists($id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }
        if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
            $user_data = $this->User->findById($id);
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'), 'flash');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'), 'flash');
            }
        } else {
            $options = array('conditions' => array('User.' . $this->User->primaryKey => $id));
            $this->request->data = $this->User->find('first', $options);
        }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, code generated by bake, hidden id, etc..
Then I found that the field id on the database was not setted to autoincrement.

I just set to autoincrement and it works